# setText() is not working

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a one `EditText` in my xml.It throws no exception but the text `"kailash"` I had set in `EditText` is not displayed. It shows me empty `EditText`. In debugging I show that compiler executing the `tx1.setText("kailash");` But dont know  this doesnt work.I have a simple `MainActivity` in that there is a search button and `onclick`of `search` button I am trying to display a dialog .Please help me. This is my code:--

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.search_dialog);
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) MainActivity.this.getLayoutInflater()
                                      .inflate(R.layout.search_dialog, null);
EditText txt1 = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.txt1);
txt1.setText("kailash");
dialog.show();
```

this is my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"  >

 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txt1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
    android:textSize="16dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: attach debugger and check what is the value of txt1 ...whether the control is going even anywhere near to it. With such less info, pretty difficult to get u help

Comment: @KailashDabhi post your full java code and xml file also.

Comment: why txt1 is declared as 'final'? Try to remove the final modifier

Comment: in debugging it shows "(id=830084844912)". that means it execute the method

Comment: it is declared final coz i want to trap event when it is edited

Comment: AFAIK 'final' equals 'const'. Trap the event in different way.

Comment: ok i have removed that but problem is not solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually the solution is very simple i was putting this code :

```
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.search_dialog);
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) MainActivity.this.getLayoutInflater()
                                  .inflate(R.layout.search_dialog, null);
```

instead of this code:

```
 RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) MainActivity.this.getLayoutInflater()
                                  .inflate(R.layout.search_dialog, null);
 dialog.setContentView(R.layout.search_dialog);
```

as activity has another layout in its setcontentView() method so it does not recognize the another layout so u should first load the layout by inflater and put it in dialog's setContentView method to make it work. hope it helps somebody . and thanks for ur support.

Answer (score 1):

```
final EditText txt1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt1);
txt1.setText("kailash");
```

call `findViewById` on your Activity Class, not a RelativeLayout you just inflate (for no reason IMHO)

Comment: i have tried that out ... and as my activity has another layout in setcontentview so my activity doesnot recognize the other layout's id

Comment: Your text is not in your activity layout ? So how do you expect it to be updated ? You should post the layout which is in your activity's setContentView...

Comment: look i want to open dialog in that activity so i think that is not a problem

Answer (score 1):

you can't change `final` - it's a constant. Define it without the final modifier, set your text, then define other instance as final

Comment: then is the relative layout added to the view you are showing? You inflate the view but you don't add it anywhere

Answer (score 1):

Back to the original post.

Kailash, it looks like the code first sets the dialog's content view from the XML layout:
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.search_dialog);

... and then creates ANOTHER instance of the same resource by inflating it into another object, layout.

Then you modify the text view in the latter, but Android shows the former view.

How about this?

EditText txt1 = (EditText) **dialog**.findViewById(R.id.txt1);

Answer (score 1):

Well, though successful, this line swap looks like magic.  May be just an implementation specific coincidence - regression prone.  It may depend on the inflater internals, where the layout objects are cached, etc.  You still inflate into an object instance potentially different from the content view.  If it happens to be the same in the current implementation, is there any guarantee it will always be the same?

OTOH, **dialog**.findViewById seems to be more robust: you just get a reference to a component in the dialog - exactly like you would do with an Activity.

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

set text like this

```
View vv;        
    LayoutInflater  inflater  =  (LayoutInflater) YourClassName.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);     
    vv = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowrelative, null);      
    EditText  edt =(EditText) vv.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    edt.setText("Ankit");       
    this.addContentView(vv, new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

Here you need to change Your Class name and Rowxml File Name

Comment: Can you explain what is the different between yours and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12457072/1050058) ?